# Why does the timer in this level go faster each time a new image is shown in tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

For my game, when a new flag is shown each time after the user clicks enter or the timer goes to zero, the timer is supposed to reset back to 20 which it does but, it goes down even faster each time the new image is shown. How do I make it so that it goes down only 1 second each time and doesn't get faster?

Here is the code to the full level:

```
def medium_level():
  global score2,current_image2, total_games,total_w
  total_games+= 1
  current_image2 =0
  score2 = 0
  new = Toplevel(window)
  new.title("Medium Mode")
  new.configure(background=bg2)
  new.geometry("600x500")
  
  ans=tk.Entry(new,font=('Times', 25))
  ans["justify"] = "center"
  ans["borderwidth"] = "1px"
  ans.place(x=90,y=270,width=414,height=188)

  rules2=tk.Label(new, font=('Times', 20),bg=bg2)
  rules2["text"] = "Enter Country Name Here:"
  rules2["justify"] = "center"
  rules2.place(x=110,y=230)

  timelbl=tk.Label(new, text="Time: ",font=('Times', 15),bg=bg2)
  timelbl.place(x=480,y=50)
  
  score_label = tk.Label(new, text="Score: 0"+"/12", font=('Times', 15),bg=bg2)
  score_label.place(x=40, y=50)

  image_label = tk.Label(master=new)
  image_label.place(relx=0.30, rely=0.10)#, relheight=0.5, relwidth=0.5)
  
  image_files = ['bangladesh.png', 'germany.png', 'turkey.png', 'egypt.png', 'madagascar.png','ecuador.png','croatia.png','palestine.png','south africa.png','mongolia.png','peru.png','vietnam.png']
  random.shuffle(image_files)
  
  def next_image2():
      global current_image2, countdown
      if current_image2 < len(image_files):
          # Get the next image and display it
          image_path = image_files[current_image2]
          image = tk.PhotoImage(file=image_path)
          image_label.configure(image=image)
          image_label.image = image

          current_image2 += 1
          countdown = 20
          start_timer()
          timelbl.config(text=f"Time: {countdown}")
          
      else:
          # Show the final score
          messagebox.showinfo("Game Over", f"Your score is: {score2}"+"/12")
          new.quit()

  def start_timer():
      global countdown
      countdown = 20
      update_timer()

  def update_timer():
      global countdown
      timelbl.config(text=f"Time: {countdown}")

      if countdown == 0:
          # Time's up, move to the next image
          next_image2()
      else:
          countdown -= 1
          new.after(1000, update_timer)
  
  def check_answer2(event):
      global score2,total_w,countdown,update_timer
      # Get the user's answer from the entry box
      user_answer = ans.get().strip().lower()

      # Get the correct answer for the current image
      correct_answer = image_files[current_image2 - 1].split('.')[0].lower()

      # Check if the user's answer is correct
      if user_answer == correct_answer:
          score2 += 1
          total_w+=1
          score_label.config(text=f"Score: {score2}"+"/12")

      # Clear the entry box
      ans.delete(0, tk.END)

      # Move to the next image
      next_image2()



  # Bind the check_answer function to the Return key press event
  ans.bind('<Return>', check_answer2)
  next_image2()
```

This is one of the ways I have tried:

```
  def start_timer():
      global countdown
      countdown = 20
      update_timer()

  def update_timer():
      global countdown
      timelbl.config(text=f"Time: {countdown}")

      if countdown == 0:
          # Time's up, move to the next image
          next_image2()
      else:
          countdown -= 1
          new.after(1000, update_timer)
```

But, for every thing I try the speed of the timer just gets faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you do not cancel the existing *countdown* when starting new countdown.

```py
after_id = None   # initialize the global after ID

def medium_level():
    ...
    def start_timer():
        global countdown, after_id # ID returned by .after()
        countdown = 20
        # cancel existing after loop if any
        if after_id:
            new.after_cancel(after_id)
            after_id = None
        update_timer()

    def update_timer():
        global countdown, after_id
        timelbl.config(text=f"Time: {countdown}")

        if countdown == 0:
            # Time's up, move to the next image
            next_image2()
        else:
            countdown -= 1
            # save the after ID
            after_id = new.after(1000, update_timer)
   ...
```